# Using range operator with a step

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, higher-order-functions, array-map

The PowerShell range operator generates a list of values:

```
>1..6

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I generate a list of values with a specific step? For example, I need a list from 1 to 10 with step 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The range operator itself doesn't support skipping/stepping, but you could use `Where-Object` (or the `Where()` method if you're running version 4.0 or above) to filter out every second:

```
PS C:\> (1..10).Where({$_ % 2 -eq 0})
2
4
6
8
10
```

Version 2.0 and up:

```
PS C:\> 1..10 |Where-Object {$_ % 2 -eq 0}
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: understand, but my powershell returns error for published sample. Updated code `(1..10) | where ({$_ % 2 -eq 0})` returns correct result

Comment: @constructor: I guess the capability to call extension methods is new in PowerShell 5. I haven't seen or used it either so far. I also think most PowerShell code should not use LINQ but rather the respective cmdlets.

Comment: Ahh, you are running PowerShell 2.0? If so, the `Where()` method doesn't exist, but yes, as mentioned, the `Where-Object` cmdlet will work just as well

Comment: @Joey The `Where()` extension method was [introduced in PowerShell 4.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857339.aspx#BKMK_core) - it's not LINQ, it's a PS language feature. OP didn't mention which version he was running

Comment: Oh, nice to know. I kinda lost track of the newer language features.

Comment: I have assuming lowest common denominator for answers lately. I am missing out on newer features as well :(

Comment: @Matt Unless there's an obvious idiomatic way of doing something, I usually try to present alternatives. `.Where()` operates significantly faster on large collections (no pipeline overhead)

Comment: I wonder why no one commented on the fact this is actually a bit different than what was requested. The steps should be offset from the original position and not from `0`, as is the common interpretation of steps on a range. Should probably update the condition in the answer to be `($_-<first-element>) % 2 -eq 0` or `1..10 |Where-Object {($_-1) % 2 -eq 0}` in this specific case.