# Loop range with steps

Tags: powershell, foreach, range

I'm trying to move from BATCH into PowerShell and I am trying to convert my own scripts.

My problem is with ranges in loop: my original BATCH script was like

```
   for /L %%U in (123,2,323) do ECHO %%U
```

and will print

```
123
125
127
...
```

with Powershell a range would be 123..323, thus

```
123..323 | % {Echo $_ }
```

Will give me

```
123
124
125
...
```

Is there a way to set a range with a step that is different than 1? All the examples I find either list all the numbers (I have hundreds...) or use the two points between the numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892174/using-range-operator-with-a-step

Comment: Thanks, I could not find this example while searching, now I will test all suggestions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple Google search should have found you this.

```
for ($i=123; $i -le 323; $i=$i+2 ) {Write-Host $i;}
```

(Initialize; condition to keep the loop running; iteration)

Comment: Thank you, I suspect I could not find this solution because I was searching for the wrong thing. Now I will study how to pass the variable onward.

Comment: @Squashman, you can also use `+=2`, _(similarly to `Set /A i+=2` with `cmd.exe`)_, e.g. `For ($i=123; $i -LE 323; $i+=2) {$i}`.

Comment: @Squashman This solution gave me the desired control over the steps (and was easy to understand since it was like counters in php) and I could successfully do a conversion of a couple of my existing BATCH scripts. Powershell ones proved to be 2x faster, so it was a needed improvement for my scripting!

Comment: @Lila Powershell does do many tasks with less code then a batch-file,  but there are still a lot of things that a batch-file can do more efficiently then PowerShell.  There are things that I can write in a batch-file that has 10 times more lines of code but runs quicker then one line of code in Powershell.

Comment: actually, google led me here. thank you for adding to the SO docs

Answer (score 4):

Using the original approach (Step 2):

```
(123..323) | % {if( $_ -band 1 ) {$_ }}
```

Step 3 and greater:

```
 (123..323) | % {if( !($i++ % 3) ) {$_ }}
```

Comment: I hardly see a resemblance with an iterating for with start, step and end values, even if your approach has the same effect.

Comment: Ok, in this case (123..323) | % {if( !($i++ % 3) ) {$_ }} is working better, but I like the approach with the fast binary operator.

Comment: I have problem in understanding how to change the step from 2 into another given number.

Comment: See comment before.

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way to create a range with a step value of *n* assuming variable `$n` contains the step value would be:

```
1..25 | ? { !($_ % $n) }
```

The `?` is an alias for the `Where-Object` cmdlet. And the `$_ % $n` can be written more explicitly as `$_ % $n -eq 0` and hence the above can also be written as:

```
1..25 | Where-Object { $_ % $n -eq 0 }
```

`Where-Object` acts as a filter and only includes the values whose modulus with the step equals 0: `$_ % $n -eq 0`.
The reason this can be written as  `!($_ % $n)` is that PowerShell treats `0` as `false` and other numbers as `true`. So, negating the `0` with `!` makes it evaluate to `true` and then causes the number to be included in the range.

So, for a step of 2 you would write:

```
123..323 | ? { !($_ % 2) }
```

This includes only even numbers (`124, 126, ...`).
To include only odd numbers, (starting from 123), a simple trick is:

```
123..323 | ? { $_ % 2 }
```

When the modulus evaluates to 1, which happens for an odd number, it is included in the final range.